# How to OwnerDraw TListView Bitmaps with vsIcon Style?

Tags: delphi

There are some good examples in StackOverFlow to ownerdraw subitems in a TListView with vsReport style but I could not find any example on how to ownerdraw bitmaps in a TListView with vsIcon Style?

My bitmaps are stored in a third-party list and are resized to 32x32.  I do not want to use an ImageList because the bitmaps are available in the third-party list.  The code shown below draws the first icon ok, but the remaining items are empty.  **Should I be doing this in some other event that has access to TRect?**

```
procedure TForm1.cxListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  iBitmap: TBitmap;
  iRect: TRect;
begin
  { Create a TBitmap }
  iBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  iBitmap.Width := 32;
  iBitmap.Height := 32;
  if Item.Index <> -1 then
  begin
    { Copy a bitmap from the list to iBitmap }
    AIEImageList.Image[Item.Index].CopyToTBitmap(iBitmap);
    { Resample the bitmap }
    iBitmap.IEResample(32, 32);
    {FIX}
    iRect := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
    { Draw the bitmap }
    Sender.Canvas.Draw(iRect.Left, iRect.Top, iBitmap);
  end;
  iBitmap.Free;
end;
```

Comment: How do you get the TRect?

Comment: Ok.. thanks... it is functional now.